# Use DLL Bytes Methods

Tags: c#, dll, byte

I have a **DLL** that some of my codes are compiled in it.
I got all bytes from that **DLL**.

So my point is to how can i use those bytes to call the Methods.

For example :

this my **DLL** Method :
    `public static string adder(string x){return x+"123";}` 
and i turned this **DLL** into bytes,

Now i want to use that method (`adder`) from the bytes that i got from the **DLL** inside my program but i don't know how.

I will be grateful if you help me.

Comment: `Assembly.Load(byte[])` will return you an `Assembly` object, then you can use all the fun reflection stuff like `GetTypes()`, `GetMethods()`, and `DynamicInvoke()`

Comment: c# is managed so you can't using an adder.  You need to use Marshal methods.  So you return the pointer to the first location as a IntPtr.  Then use Marshal.Copy() method to copy array to a c# byte[].